# Text Duplicating in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, spacebars

I'm attempting to make a Meteor app which allows multiple people to edit a body of text concurrently (think Google Docs/Drive).

I figure in order to do this, I need to have a template which just shows the text that's currently in the database, and then whenever the text is modified, it needs to update the text in the database.

I was able to reproduce the same problems from my full app in this minimal reproduction below (designed to be used by a single user instead of multiple, thus swapped from using a Mongo Collection to a Session.)

```
<body>
  {{> hello}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
  <pre contentEditable="true">{{text}}</pre>
</template>
```

(The exact same problem happens if I use a `div` instead of a `pre`.)

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Session.setDefault('text', "Edit me!");

  Template.hello.helpers({
    text: function () {
      return Session.get('text');
    }
  });

  Template.hello.events({
    "input pre": function (event) {
      Session.set('text', $(event.target).text());
    }
  });
}
```

Try typing a bit in the application and the bug should pretty quickly be apparent to you: with each keystroke it takes all of the existing text and appends it to what you've typed (so with each keystroke, it duplicates all the text). Here's the really weird part: this behavior doesn't always start immediately... in fact, I haven't found any particularly reliable ways of reproducing it. Once it has duplicated the text a single time, it'll reliably do it again and again with each keystroke, up until you refresh the page. After you refresh the page, sometimes the bug appears again with your next keystroke, other times it can take ~20 keystrokes before it appears.

I've tested this on Safari 8 (both OS X and iOS), Chrome (both OS X and Windows), and Firefox (just OS X) and the issue appears in every browser.

If you haven't been able to reproduce it yet, try highlighting all the text, deleting it, and typing. Also try starting a new line. I find those actions seem to have a higher probability of starting the text duplication, but even those don't consistently start the issue.

My questions are:

1. Why is this bug occurring?
2. How can I stop it from occurring?

If you'd like to see the problem first hand without having to run a meteor server (although I gave you everything you all the code already...) I threw it up [here](http://minimalreproduction.meteor.com).

Comment: You won't be able to use Session for multi-user editing sorry, as it's only available in the browser client (and also does not persist like a cookie does, so when you refresh it's gone). You need to use a Collection so that all users can retrieve the contents.

Comment: @IanJones: Please see paragraph 3 of my question, where I explained that I was able to reproduce my specific issue with Sessions instead of Collections. I did that to minimize how much code I needed to share (it's also a good idea to make a minimal reproduction of a problem when you're trying to get to its root cause.)

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted... I see now that you meant this uses Session only for the sake of example. How exactly is 'input pre' an event? Doesn't seem  like an event type to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue, discussed in details [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1964). I am using [this solution](https://github.com/Swavek/contenteditable) (from Swavek) and it works well.

Simply put, the issue arises when two guys manipulate the same DOM elements at the same time:

1. Meteor, though reactivity
2. The browser code responsible for managing the inside of the contenteditable div.

The solution is to tell Meteor not to manipulate the inside of the contenteditable div, but to refresh the whole div instead. You do it like this:

```
<body>
  {{> hello}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
  {{{getContenteditableDiv}}}  <!-- Beware: triple brackets! -->
</template>

Template.hello.helpers({
  getContenteditableDiv: function() {
    return '<pre contentEditable="true">' + Session.get('text') + '</pre>';
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for sharing this. There seems to be issues with it, though. When I run this, `this.text` returns `undefined`. Also, after the page loads and `getContenteditableDiv` gets called the first time, it never gets called again. For my minimal reproduction, that doesn't matter since the session is never set from anywhere else, but in my full application it's possible for edits to be coming in from other users updating the database. Basically, I'm concerned that this will break reactivity.

Comment: I'm upvoting this because it the links at the start which were relevant and seem like they should be useful. But, as I commented a few hours ago, the code isn't actually working for me right now so I'm not going to accept it until the code in it is fixed.

Comment: I have updated my answer to stick more to your sample code where 'text' is taken from a Session variable rather than the template context. Please let me know if this works for you. Reactivity should not be broken.

Comment: Okay, with that edit it works now so I've marked it as accepted. It seems to me at this point that the `Template.hello.helpers` named `text` is no longer required. Am I missing some subtle detail of how this solution works, or am I correct in thinking that I can remove that now?

Comment: Yes, you can remove the 'text' helper.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you're capturing all events instead of narrowing it down to a specific event type.

I just tried this on [MeteorPad](http://meteorpad.com) for a few minutes and it never duplicated the text:

**/main.html**

```
<body>
  {{> hello}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
  <pre contentEditable="true">{{text}}</pre>
</template>
```

**/client/app.js**

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Session.setDefault('text', "Edit me!");

  Template.hello.helpers({
    text: function () {
      return Session.get('text');
    }
  });

  Template.hello.events({
    "keyup pre": function (event) {
      $(event.target).text("I was called");
      Session.set('text', $(event.target).text());
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried this yet, but I suspect that the reason you think this code doesn't have the problem that mine does is because it's invalid and so the body of the function is never run. That means the database isn't getting updated with the latest copy of the code (or, the session in the case of my minimal reproduction). Not updating the backing store means that meteor never sees updated text and never tries to insert it into the same text field. I'm not certain, but I'm pretty sure "keyup input pre" isn't a valid thing in Meteor... and if it is, it's a superset, not subset, of "input pre"

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare - No, it hadn't crossed my mind about it being invalid code. I just went to meteorpad.com and copied your example to test. Then I added the `keyup` event prefix and it stopped duplicating the text, so you might want to try it out yourself.

Comment: Yeah, it's invalid and never gets called if you add `keyup`. As a simple way of verifying in the minimal reproduction on MeteorPad, replace the body of the function with `$(event.target).text("I was called.");`. If the function was ever called, it would replace the text on the page with that, but since it isn't, you can edit the text just fine (it's just an ordinary HTML `contentEditable` without Meteor doing anything at all, in that case. But I want Meteor to be keeping the text in sync with my backing store.)

Comment: Hmmm... Very strange. I used your example and now see what you mean. However I removed the "input" part since you only have a "pre" field in the example and it started firing the Session.set code. Using your example, it now overwrites the input field, but at least it's firing.

Comment: I want it to fire, and it fires fine in my original. The problem is that, for some reason, when Spacebars is told that the backing store has changed, it decides to insert the text into the field twice. The backing store actually has the exact text that it should (I can query Mongo and verify that, in my full program... you could log the session variable to verify it in my minimal reproduction.) Just for some reason Spacebars chooses to render it as if my template was `{{text}}{{text}}` instead of just `{{text}}`.

Comment: If you want to see more on what valid events look like in Meteor, I just found the docs on them here: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/eventmaps

Comment: Thanks for posting the docs, as it clarifies a misunderstanding that I had about Meteor. Wish I could help more, but I think I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

This both feels and looks like a hack... but it's slightly better than the original code so I'll share it as an answer:

After each `input`, after inserting the new contents into the backing store, clear out the field using `$(event.target).contents().remove();`.

Example:

```
Template.hello.events({
  "input pre": function (event) {
    Session.set('text', $(event.target).text());
    $(event.target).contents().remove();
  }
});
```

Caveats:

1. The text momentarily disappears after each keystroke (sometimes it's so brief you don't even notice it.)
2. The cursor jumps back to the start of the text every time you type. (But the cursor had a tendency to jump around in the original code, too.)

Both of the caveats are pretty terrible... basically all that has happened is I swapped duplicate text appearing with having the text momentarily disappearing.

A real solution would be if there's some kind of way I could like, hook into spacebars or something... like, I need to have some code that runs right after spacebars reactively updates. Or if I could modify how spacebars reactively updates. Maybe I'll look into the documentation and/or source on Spacebars and file a bug report or feature request based on what I find...